# What is the best way to embed another HTTP message inside of a HTTP Header?

Tags: http, encoding, http-headers

What is the most efficient and robust way to embed an entire HTTP message inside of another HTTP message's header(s)?  Don't ask why.  :)

FWIW, either message could be a request or a response, but I am primarily concerned with embedding a response within a request.

I am unable to see the best way to encode the embedded message, which in my case definitely has CRLFs. Assuming the HTTP message to be embedded is valid, are there any other characters I need to be concerned with?

I am aware of header size restrictions of certain web servers thanks to other posts, so should I span across multiple headers to solve for this?
x1, x2, x3, etc:

Do you foresee any security concerns with this approach?
My primary concern is encoding, then size, then security.

Thanks for your advice and solutions in advance.

Comment: Must it be in the header? You can encapsulate an HTTP message within another HTTP message's body (not the headers) by setting the `Content-Type` header to [`message/http`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-8.3.1).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Andrew Lambert.  I was unaware of that Content-Type, but I believe I do need to pass the message as a header.  The original message needs to be fully functional and my header should be ignored except for by my processor.  At least, that is my intent, and why I chose a "header".